# PHP/PDO more efficient method of rows?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have all my sites built on php and mysql stack using PDO. I am well aware of the various ways to find out how many rows a specific query can return but I am not sure how to find out which is more efficient.

### Method 1 - COUNT() in SQL

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM table WHERE name = :name');
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $counter = $row[0];
}
```

in this example, I am ONLY interested in counting the number of results for a specific query. The query is made once and results are returned in a $counter variable.

### Method 2 - Foundrows

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT ID FROM table WHERE name = :name');
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->execute();

$counter= $db->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchColumn();
```

This method issues a follow up call to my initial query.

Method one seems to be the most 'efficient' in terms of only making one query to the database and finding the result. Method 2 gives the added benefit of allowing me to retrieve a set of results, then based on the count of those results choose to disregard or continue. Method 2, however, appears to make subsequent calls which i would assume is less efficient.

Any seasoned advice on this?

note: in this example, I am **ONLY** interested in what is more efficient to find the number of result rows. Additional FYI info about added benefits of each is appreciated but not the point of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1 is more efficient.
If `id` is not the primary key, then replace `count(id)` with `count(*)` for extra speed *(maybe faster, never slower)*.
If you don't have an index on `name` add one for speed.

Comment: it was my understanding COUNT(*) counted the results of all columns whereas COUNT(ID) (an indexed or primary column) would be much faster. Is this not the case?

Comment: @JM4, no you have it all wrong. `COUNT(*)` counts all rows, plain and simple. `count(columnname)` counts all non-null instances of columnname. The latter involves an extra test and can be slower if `columnname` is not the primary key.

Comment: m8, he said if id was **not** the primary key, then perform count(*) instead